# Как сделать, чтобы Debian (cubieboard) через tty передавал данные в arduino и получал обратно?

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, микроконтроллеры

Здравствуйте.

Для начала расскажу, что у меня есть и чего я хочу добиться, а далее сам вопрос.

У меня есть cubieboard a10 (если кто не знает, это что-то типа мини-компьютера, туда можно ставить любую ОС, обычно это Debian) и arduino UNO (если кто не знает, это плата с микроконтроллером, программируется на c++).
cubieboard и arduino можно подключить через USB A -> USB B (как обычно подключается принтер).
В cubieboard он определяется как обычный tty терминал.
На cubieboard легко ставится WEB сервер.

Так вот, я хочу сделать так:  
На WEB сервер создаём страницу с, допустим, 3 кнопками: передать 1, 2, 3.
И при нажатии на одну из кнопок предаётся значение по tty в arduino, он, допустим, умножает это число на 5 и отправляет обратно, и у пользователя отображается это умноженное число.

Я вполне могу сделать такую страницу, через nodejs могу получить нажатия на кнопки и отправить ответ обратно.
На arduino могу написать программу, которая будет получать число, умножать и отправлять обратно.

---

Но как сделать, чтобы Debian (cubieboard) через tty передавал и получал это значение обратно? Я не знаю, как это сделать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать?
Возможно, нужно использовать не nodejs, а что-то другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Arduino не определяется, ищем драйвера своей модели Arduino для Linux (они есть)
Устанавливаем через NPM модуль [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) (npm install serialport)
Вот пример кода с использованием этого модуля:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
//Определям скорость, путь и разделитель строк
var serial = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {baudrate: 9600,parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")});

serial.on("open", function() {//Ждём подключения
        serial.on('data', function(data){//Как придут данные вывести их в лог
                console.log(data);
        });
        serial.write("start");//Оправляем строку "start"
});
```

В Arduino работаем через функцию [Serial](http://arduino.ru/Reference/Serial)

Answer (score 3):

> В cubieboard он определяется как обычный tty терминал.
> Возможно, нужно использовать не nodejs, а что-то другое?

Если я верно все понял, то используйте bash.

Отправка данных со стороны dedian:

```
echo «hello tty» > /dev/ttyX
```

Получение данных со стороны arduino (если там есть shell)
`cat /dev/ttyX` либо ваша программа с той стороны получает данные и обрабатывает, надо понять, какой у вас обратный интерфейс со стороны arduino, чтоб понять, откуда получать и куда отправлять, возможно, что и получать от arduino данные в debian вам надо будет, спрашивая `cat /dev/ttyX`.

Может быть, это то, что вам нужно:

http://brandontilley.com/2012/03/02/controlling-an-arduino-from-nodejs.html

Comment: А подробнее можно?

Comment: Ну, если он у вас как терминал и имеет командный интерфейс, то бишь командную строку, то и общайтесь с ним через `shell`, он же у вас как устройство `/dev/tty`, если я понимаю.
Посмотрите https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Внес в ответ коррективы с примерами.

Comment: Допустим, через echo я смогу передать данные, но что дальше?
Мне нужно, чтобы данные отправлялись при нажатии на кнопу, которая находится на локальном сайте.

Или нужно делать, допустим, так:
NodeJS получает данные о том, что кнопка нажата, и запускает bash скрипт?

Comment: Можно попробовать вызвать из nodejs скрипт bash:

    child = exec("/bin/bash " + 'bash.sh params',
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            ...
        }
    );

Есть вариант использовать вот это https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

А вот тут, по-моему, именно то, что вам нужно:

http://brandontilley.com/2012/03/02/controlling-an-arduino-from-nodejs.html

Дописал ссылку в ответ, надеюсь, вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли мне!